# Embarcadero Delphi VCL - Name of component

Tags: delphi, vcl

What is the name of this visual component? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might be the common [`TButton`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TButton) component in [`bsCommandLink`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomButton.TButtonStyle) style (set by the [`Style`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TButton.Style) property).

Answer (score 3):

TLama's educated guess might very well be right.

In general, to answer questions of this nature you can use Spy++ (or any other similar tool) to find the window class name. That should be enough to identify the control.